# Main Branch is not updated without pull request in azure devops repository

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have commit the code in featured branch but PR is automatically raise and updated main branch.
How to stop PR raise.

Comment: Do you have a pipeline that is has a create pull request action in it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Create Pull Request extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest) in Azure DevOps, it can automatically create a Pull Request from your Build or Release Pipeline. Please double-check your pipeline tasks and make sure there is no such task to create the pull request.